# MITMPROXY make output human readable to file

Tags: proxy, mitmproxy

My system:

```
Ubuntu 16.04
Mitmproxy version 3.0.4
Python version 3.5.2
```

I've successfully installed `mitmproxy` from: [docs.mitmproxy.org](https://docs.mitmproxy.org/stable/overview-installation/) on my server. But now I got confused how to save log mitmproxy to file? I try use `mitmdump --mode transparent --showhost -p 9001 -w output_file`

While I open `output_file`, it's not human readable. I read the docs and try scripts from the mitmproxy's Github, but no clue.

Anyone know how to save log mitmproxy to file, but human readable?
Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

As you have probably noticed, mitmproxy generates streams in a binary format. If you want to save the streams in a human readable format, you can pass a script when you run mitmproxy to do so.

`save.py`

```py
from mitmproxy.net.http.http1.assemble import assemble_request, assemble_response

f = open('/tmp/test/output.txt', 'w')

def response(flow):
    f.write(assemble_request(flow.request).decode('utf-8'))
```

And now run `mitmproxy -s save.py` and the output will be written to `output.txt` in a human readable format.

Do pay attention to the responses because they might contain a lot of binary data. but if you do want to write the responses also in a human readable format, then you can add `f.write(assemble_response(flow.response).decode('utf-8', 'replace'))` to the script.

Example output from the script:

```
❯❯ tail -f output.txt
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:77.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/77.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
If-Modified-Since: Thu, 17 Oct 2019 07:18:26 GMT
If-None-Match: "3147526947"
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

Comment: how would I transform an existing file?

Comment: Is it possible to reverse this as well? As in, convert the binary to human readable format and then revert it back to binary ?

Answer (score 0):

I initially had trouble getting the requests and responses output to file using what @securisec proposed but what worked for me was to replace `mitmproxy -s save.py` with `mitmdump -s save.py` instead.

Once I killed the mitmdump process, the output file was written to the file system.